# Null pointer exception using Autowired annotation - Gemfire Listerner

Tags: spring, spring-data-cassandra, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I have moved all the Cassandra into single class. When I tried create instance of CassandraOperations in the gemfire cache listener was getting null pointer exception.Can you please assist me on this error

I have not received any null pointer exception using spring and cassandra but getting while integrating with gemfire.

```
@Component  
public class CacheListener<K, V> extends CacheListenerAdapter<K, V> implements Declarable {

@Autowired
private CassandraOperations cassandraOperations;

@Override
public void init(Properties props) {

}

public void afterCreate(EntryEvent e) {
    cassandraOperations.insert(e.getNewValue());

}

@Override
public void close() {
}

}



public class CassandraConfig {
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CassandraConfig.class);
@Bean
public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
    cluster.setContactPoints(environment.getProperty("cassandra.contactpoints"));
    cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("cassandra.port")));
    return cluster;
}
@Bean
public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() {
    BasicCassandraMappingContext mappingContext = new BasicCassandraMappingContext(); 
    mappingContext.setUserTypeResolver(new SimpleUserTypeResolver(cluster().getObject(), environment.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace"))); return mappingContext;
}
@Bean
public CassandraConverter converter() {
    return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
}
@Bean
public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {
    CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
    session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
    session.setKeyspaceName(environment.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace"));
    session.setConverter(converter());
    session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);
    return session;
}
@Bean
public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());
}
}
```

**Exception**

```
[error 2017/05/05 11:16:04.874 CDT <http-nio-7878-exec-1> tid=0x5b] Exception occurred in CacheListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CacheListener.afterCreate(CacheListener.java:27)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.EnumListenerEvent$AFTER_CREATE.dispatchEvent(EnumListenerEvent.java:97)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.dispatchEvent(LocalRegion.java:8897)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.dispatchListenerEvent(LocalRegion.java:7376)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.invokePutCallbacks(LocalRegion.java:6158)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.EntryEventImpl.invokeCallbacks(EntryEventImpl.java:1919)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.ProxyRegionMap$ProxyRegionEntry.dispatchListenerEvents(ProxyRegionMap.java:548)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.basicPutPart2(LocalRegion.java:6012)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.ProxyRegionMap.basicPut(ProxyRegionMap.java:232)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.virtualPut(LocalRegion.java:5824)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegionDataView.putEntry(LocalRegionDataView.java:118)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.basicPut(LocalRegion.java:5214)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.validatedPut(LocalRegion.java:1597)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.put(LocalRegion.java:1580)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.AbstractRegion.put(AbstractRegion.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.GemfireTemplate.put(GemfireTemplate.java:189)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.repository.support.SimpleGemfireRepository.save(SimpleGemfireRepository.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: There is no exception using between cassandra and spring. Instance of Cassandra operation is not creating in gemfire listerner

Comment: This is not duplicate

Comment: Did you downvote my answer to you?!

Comment: its not not me. Your explanation was excellent. Not yet integrated your code.

Comment: Sorry, yeah that is weird.  There was a panel on SO that looked like the downvote came from you, but in revisiting it, I don't think that is reliable.  I upvoted your question because I think it is valid and it definitely did not deserve a -1, who ever did that, argh.  Anyway, hope my answer helps, and if you have further questions, let me know.  I can follow up.  I am 1 of 2 leads for Spring Data Cassandra and the lead for Spring Data GemFire.  Of course, I am far more knowledgeable about GemFire; still learning the ropes on Cassandra yet, :-)  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks John, your solutions worked. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Your welcome, glad that helped.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is not apparent in your code/configuration above is how you configured your application-specific, GemFire `CacheListener` using *Spring* (*Data GemFire*).

I see you annotated your application `CacheListener` using *Spring's* `@Component` stereo-type annotation, but this does nothing without help.

Are you using *Spring's* [Classpath component scanning](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-classpath-scanning) functionality, or perhaps *Spring's* [Annotation-based container configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-annotation-config) support?  If you are using the later, you know you have to still explicitly define your application `CacheListener` in config (JavaConfig or XML), right?

Whenever you encounter a `NullPointerException` on an `@Autowired` component/collaborator field to inject a dependency, especially when using *Spring's* [@Autowired](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) annotation, it is good indication you have a configuration problem, particularly since the `@Autowired` annotation implies that the "dependency" (e.g. `CassandraOperations`) is "**required**" (unless you explicitly set the [required](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html#required--) attribute of the `@Autowired` annotation to **false**, which you did not; `required` defaults to **true**).

Therefore, if the `CacheListener` component were picked up in the scan and a dependency could not be injected (auto-wired) because no (other) bean of the specified type (e.g. `CassandraOperations`) was defined in the *Spring* application context (which it is), then *Spring* would throw an Exception when evaluating your configuration class(es).

Although, even your `CassandraConfig` class must also be annotated with *Spring's* `@Configuration` annotation or with the `@Component` annotation when using either *Spring* Classpath component scanning or Annotation-based container config.  Or, it must be explicitly defined as a bean in the *Spring* application context if using neither.

NOTE: the naming convention (i.e. `CacheListener`) is not very good since it clashes with GemFire's own [CacheListener](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/CacheListener.html) interface.  It would be better to call your application-specific extension/implementation perhaps, "`GemFireToCassandraCacheListener`"

By way of example...

```
import ...;

@Configuration
class GemFireConfiguration {

  @Bean
  CacheFactoryBean gemfireCache() {
    return new CacheFactoryBean();
  }

  @Bean("CassandraCache")
  PartitionedRegionFactoryBean cassandraCacheRegion() {
    PartitionedRegionFactoryBean cassandraCacheRegion = 
      new PartitionedRegionFactoryBean();

    cassandraCacheRegion.setCache(gemfireCache());
    cassandraCacheRegion.setClose(false);
    cassandraCacheRegion.setCacheListeners(
      new CacheListener[] { gemfireToCassandraCacheListener() });

    return cassandraCacheRegion;
  }

  @Bean
  GemFireToCassandraCacheListener gemfireToCassandraCacheListener() {
    return new GemFireToCassandraCacheListener();
  }
}

import ...;

@Configuration
class CassandraConfig {

  // what you have above
}
```

I have plenty of GemFire configuration examples [here](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/tree/master/configuration-example/src/main/java/example/app), that shows GemFire native config with *Spring (Data GemFire)* config, XML vs. JavaConfig vs. annotations, etc, etc.

Finally...

Technically, it might be better to use a GemFire [CacheWriter](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/CacheWriter.html), attached to the Region, rather than a `CacheListener`, since what you are doing (updating Cassandra on a cache create) is the intended purpose of a `CacheWriter`.

Of course, the `CacheListener` is called ["after" create](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/CacheListener.html#afterCreate-org.apache.geode.cache.EntryEvent-) vs. the `CacheWriter` which is ["before" create](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/CacheWriter.html#beforeCreate-org.apache.geode.cache.EntryEvent-).  However, I would say it is always better to update the "**primary**" data source (or "*source of truth*") before updating the "cache" to reflect the data source.  This is applicable especially if there are constraints in the primary data source that might cause an update to fail.  You would not want the cache to be updated if the primary data source could not be.

A `CacheWriter` is configured similarly to a `CacheListener`, like so...

```
  @Bean("CassandraCache")
  PartitionedRegionFactoryBean cassandraCacheRegion() {
    PartitionedRegionFactoryBean cassandraCacheRegion = 
      new PartitionedRegionFactoryBean();

    cassandraCacheRegion.setCache(gemfireCache());
    cassandraCacheRegion.setClose(false);
    cassandraCacheRegion.setCacheWriter(gemfireToCassandraCacheWriter());

    return cassandraCacheRegion;
  }

  @Bean
  GemFireToCassandraCacheWriter gemfireToCassandraCacheWriter(
      CassandraOperations cassandraOperations) {

    return new GemFireToCassandraCacheWriter(cassandraOperations);
  }
```

Where the `GemFireToCassandraCacheWriter` would be defined as...

```
class GemFireToCassandraCacheWriter extends CacheWriterAdapter {

  private CassandraOperations cassandraOperations;

  // Using constructor injection is better than field injection
  GemFireToCassandraCacheWriter(CassandraOperations cassandraOperations) {
    this.cassandraOperations = cassandraOperations;
  }

  public void beforeCreate(EntryEvent<?, ?> event) {
    cassandraOperations.insert(event.getNewValue());
  }
}
```

NOTE: a Region can only have 1 `CacheWriter`.  FYI, functionally the `CacheWriter` is the counterpart to a [CacheLoader](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/CacheLoader.html). See the [GemFire User Guide](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/gemfire/about_gemfire.html) for more details.  In particular, see [here](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/events/list_of_event_handlers_and_events.html), [here](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/events/event_handler_overview.html) and [here](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/outside_data_sources/sync_outside_data.html).

Additionally, if you are just using GemFire as a cache for state that is primarily managed in Cassandra, then you might also consider [Spring's Cache Abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache), for which *Spring Data GemFire* [positions GemFire](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#apis:spring-cache-abstraction) as a "provider" in the abstraction.

Not sure what your GemFire to Cassandra UC is all about, but food for thought.

Hope this helps!

-John